# Configure Infinispan as second level cache in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, orm, infinispan

I am trying to configure infinispan for caching in hibernate. Please can someone provide me with the steps that i need to follow and the configurations that i need to add in the infinispan-cache.xml file

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add the following Hibernate properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />    
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager" value="java:CacheManager" />
```

Then you need to set the Entity cache selection policy:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
```

Only the entities annotated with `@javax.persistence.Cacheable` would be stored in the second-level cache.

Comment: Thank you. Where is the CacheManager stored? What will my configuration look like?